# Grep pattern match between very large files is way too slow

Tags: regex, linux, grep, large-files, sequencing

I've spent way too much time on this and am looking for suggestions. I have too very large files (FASTQ files from an Illumina sequencing run for those interested). What I need to do is match a pattern common between both files and print that line plus the 3 lines below it into two separate files without duplications (which exist in the original files). Grep does this just fine but the files are ~18GB and matching between them is ridiculously slow. Example of what I need to do is below.

**FileA:**

```
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/1
NTTTCAGTTAGGGCGTTTGAAAACAGGCACTCCGGCTAGGCTGGTCAAGG
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/1
BP\cccc^ea^eghffggfhh`bdebgfbffbfae[_ffd_ea[H\_f_c
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/1
NAGGATTTAAAGCGGCATCTTCGAGATGAAATCAATTTGATGTGATGAGC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/1
BP\ccceeggggfiihihhiiiihiiiiiiiiihighiighhiifhhhic
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:2316:21261:100790#ATAGCG/1
TGTTCAAAGCAGGCGTATTGCTCGAATATATTAGCATGGAATAATAGAAT
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:2316:21261:100790#ATAGCG/1
__\^c^ac]ZeaWdPb_e`KbagdefbZb[cebSZIY^cRaacea^[a`c
```

You can see 3 unique headers starting with `@` followed by 3 additional lines

**FileB:**

```
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/2
GAAATCAATGGATTCCTTGGCCAGCCTAGCCGGAGTGCCTGTTTTCAAAC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/2
_[_ceeeefffgfdYdffed]e`gdghfhiiihdgcghigffgfdceffh
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
GCCATTCAGTCCGAATTGAGTACAGTGGGACGATGTTTCAAAGGTCTGGC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
_aaeeeeegggggiiiiihihiiiihgiigfggiighihhihiighhiii
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
GCCATTCAGTCCGAATTGAGTACAGTGGGACGATGTTTCAAAGGTCTGGC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
_aaeeeeegggggiiiiihihiiiihgiigfggiighihhihiighhiii
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
GCCATTCAGTCCGAATTGAGTACAGTGGGACGATGTTTCAAAGGTCTGGC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
_aaeeeeegggggiiiiihihiiiihgiigfggiighihhihiighhiii
```

There are 4 headers here but only 2 are unique as one of them is repeated 3 times

I need the common headers between the two files without duplicates plus the 3 lines below them. In the same order in each file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
grep -E @DLZ38V1.*/ --only-matching FileA | sort -u -o FileA.sorted
grep -E @DLZ38V1.*/ --only-matching FileB | sort -u -o FileB.sorted
comm -12 FileA.sorted FileB.sorted > combined
```

combined

```
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/
```

This is only the common headers between the two files without duplicates. This is what I want.
Now I need to match these headers to the original files and grab the 3 lines below them but only once.

If I use grep I can get what I want for each file

```
while read -r line; do
   grep -A3 -m1 -F $line FileA
done < combined > FileA.Final
```

**FileA.Final**

```
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/1
NAGGATTTAAAGCGGCATCTTCGAGATGAAATCAATTTGATGTGATGAGC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/1
BP\ccceeggggfiihihhiiiihiiiiiiiiihighiighhiifhhhic
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/1
NTTTCAGTTAGGGCGTTTGAAAACAGGCACTCCGGCTAGGCTGGTCAAGG
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/1
BP\cccc^ea^eghffggfhh`bdebgfbffbfae[_ffd_ea[H\_f_c
```

The while loop is repeated to generate **FileB.Final**

```
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
GCCATTCAGTCCGAATTGAGTACAGTGGGACGATGTTTCAAAGGTCTGGC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1369:2106#ATAGCG/2
_aaeeeeegggggiiiiihihiiiihgiigfggiighihhihiighhiii
@DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/2
GAAATCAATGGATTCCTTGGCCAGCCTAGCCGGAGTGCCTGTTTTCAAAC
+DLZ38V1_0262:8:1101:1430:2087#ATAGCG/2
```

This works but FileA and FileB are ~18GB and my combined file is around ~2GB. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can dramatically speed up the last step?

Comment: Rather than doing one `grep` for each header, re-scanning the entire file each time, why not put all the headers in a file and do `grep -A3 -m1 -F -f header_list.txt FileA`?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that with the -m1 this is killed after the first hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I should post the fix I came up with for this. Once I obtained the combined file (above) I used a perl hash reference to read them into memory and scan file A. Matches in file A were hashed and used to scan file B. This still takes a lot of memory but works very fast. From 20+ days with grep to ~20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often do you need to run this:

1. you could dump (you'll probably want bulk inserts with the index built afterwards) your data into a Postgres (sqlite?) database, build an index on it, and enjoy the fruits of 40 years of research into efficient implementations of relational databases with practically no investment from you.
2. you could mimic having a relational database by using the unix utility 'join', but there wouldn't be much joy, since that doesn't give you an index, yet it is likely to be faster than 'grep', you might hit physical limitations...I never tried to join two 18G files.
3. you could write a bit of C code (put your favourite compiled (to machine code) language here), which converts your strings (four letters only, right?) into binary and builds an index (or more) based on it. This could be made lightning fast and small memory footprint as your fifty character string would take up only two 64bit words.